# is this syntax allowed with Bundler gem 'x', :group => :development, :require => false

Tags: ruby, bundler

I've been reading through the docs of [Bundler](http://bundler.io/v1.5/) to see if I can run this line:

```
gem 'thin', :group => :development, :require => false
```

But I could not find something like this. The only syntax that is mentioned is:

```
gem 'thin', :group => :development

#or this

   gem 'thin',:require => false
```

But not the two together. Does anyone know if I am allowed to use Bundler this way, or the only way I can do it is with blocks:

```
group :test do
  gem 'thin',:require => false
end
```

Comment: @IsmailBadawi - I have tried it, but just wanted to make sure that is a valid syntax

Answer (score 2, accepted):

The `:group => :development, :require => false` stuff is really just a Hash of options for the `gem` method, there's nothing magical here, just a simple Hash. The [documentation](http://bundler.io/v1.5/man/gemfile.5.html) simply says:

> **GEMS (#gem)**
>   Specify gem requirements using the gem method, with the following arguments. All parameters are OPTIONAL unless otherwise specified.

followed by a list of options so you can combine the options as needed. In fact, I have things like this:

```
gem 'gettext', '~> 2.0', :require => false, :group => :development
gem 'ruby_parser',       :require => false, :group => :development
```

in one of my `Gemfile`s and it works fine.

Answer (score -2):

This should work

```
gem 'thin', group: :development, require: false
```

Comment: That's exactly the same as `gem 'thin', :group => :development, :require => false` as far as Ruby is concerned.

Comment: "Try it and see" isn't really a valid answer by Stack Overflow standards.

Comment: But it will work, I'm just asking because the questioner has the answer, so I was wondering if he did try it.

Comment: Then post it as a comment.